# How do I get an addresses latitude-longitude using HTML5 geolocation or Google API?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I am getting baffled with a problem that is, I can get the location of a user from Facebook and all I need is to get the latitude and longitude of that location, but I still couldn't find a solution.

It will help if I can get that latitude and longitude using an HTML5 geolocation or any Google API. What is the solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} else {
    alert('It seems like Geolocation, which is required for this page, is not enabled in your browser. Please use a browser which supports it.');
}
```

If the browser supports geolocation and if `getCurrentPosition` runs successfully, then a success function is called. And then in the function `successFunction`

have

```
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log('Your latitude is :'+lat+' and longitude is '+long);
}
```

Read more on the Geolocation API here

- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/how-to-use-the-w3c-geolocation-api/ (Disclaimer: my article)
- http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html (The Spec)

Comment: Where to you call successFunction() ?

Answer (score 4):

Flyleaf, I work at [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) where we also provide an API to get the coordinates of addresses; it's called [LiveAddress API](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api).

As Bart mentioned, Google's TOS won't allow you to geocode without showing a Google Map, and what's more is you can't store the results. If you're looking to locate an *address* as you've suggested, I recommend something like LiveAddress which will actually verify the validity of the address as well -- these other APIs and HTML5 will not do that.

Hope you find something that works for you. The question right now is a little vague, but maybe this will help. It might go something like this ([with Javascript](http://smartystreets.com/kb/liveaddress-api/javascript)):

```
LiveAddress.geocode(address, function(geo) {
    alert("The address is at: " + geo.coords);
});
```

Comment: Is SmartyStreets US only or do you support Europe as well? The API wasn't able to find my address in the Netherlands.

Comment: It's US-only, but it's *really* good at US addresses. :) For international cases, we recommend sending US addresses through LiveAddress, or any others through another API of your choice, but realize that most APIs won't actually verify the deliverability/validity of the international address.

Comment: @flyleaf SmartyStreets now does international address verification

Answer (score 2):

I found the best option to be to use [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org) directly via a sub-project ([Nominatim](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/)) API they have.

[API documentation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim)

Example [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) call: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=35.958&lon=-83.952&zoom=18

Note that while their terms of service does allow direct client-side use from browser JavaScript, they don't want high-volume use and suggest using your server as a proxy to add caching and so it can be easily switched. The data is available for download, and instructions are provided for setting up a locally query-able database of the data.

Comment: The API documentation points to Wikipedia, it should point to: https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Overview/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Gisgraphy](http://www.gisgraphy.com/) a free an open source geo service.

Everyone will tell you to use the Google Maps API but read the [terms of use](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).

> (g) No Use of Content without a Google Map. You must not use or
>   display the Content without a corresponding Google map, unless you are
>   explicitly permitted to do so in the Maps APIs Documentation, or
>   through written permission from Google. In any event, you must not use
>   or display the Content on or in conjunction with a non-Google map. For
>   example, you must not use geocodes obtained through the Service in
>   conjunction with a non-Google map. As another example, you must not
>   display Street View imagery alongside a non-Google map, but you may
>   display Street View imagery without a corresponding Google map because
>   the Maps APIs Documentation explicitly permits you to do so.

So with the Google API you **must use a Google Map**. So if you need a map you're OK.

Answer (score 0):

> It will help if I can get that latitude and longitude using an HTML5 geolocation

Well, then just do exactly that – where exactly is your problem with it?

That’s what the [`getCurrentPosition` method](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#get-current-position) [is for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_geolocation#Getting_the_current_position).